# Domain model and class diagram

Tags: uml

I was wondering if it was possible to have differences between my conceptual model and the class diagram?

In the conceptual model, I explain that the user can create a message.

But in the class diagram the user must go through a class that contains all methods of creating a "ManageMessage" message.

here is an example

[image]
[image]

Can you help me ? Thank you

Comment: ManageMessage is not a valid class. It’s not even a noun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you how you show your classes in different diagrams. So in one you can show detailed attributes and operations and in another you show just the class name. However, in most cases it's better to create domain model which focuses on business aspects in the beginning. It does not have technically imposed structural elements and mainly you use attributes (YMMV). Later you derive a technical design from that model where you create a copy that links back with `<<trace>>` dependencies (UML tools offer transformation for that). Although you have to (mostly) manually synch the two models it's best to communicate with either business and developers.

N.B. about your design above: A message with zero related users does not seem to make much sense. Also you should not use the shared aggregation since it has no defined semantics.

Comment: thank you for your reply
Regarding my design, it would be better to say that 1 .. * user can create a message?

I did not understand your message about aggregation, by which I mean that my management uses the message class.

Comment: Yes. 1..* is better. Shared aggregation has no defined semantics and should only be used in domains where you define it manually (written so in the UML 2.5 specs). Aggregation at all is about life time of objects which in almost all cases is just irrelevant (only in security and memory management domains it has a use). Just leave it away.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Kilian :)